# rawPassword cannot be null

Tags: java, reactjs, typescript, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm learning Java Springboot and creating todo app with React(TypeScript) and Springboot now.

I want to signup but **once I try to call api for signup, Error occurs and says "rawPassword cannot be null" from springboot.**

I'm making frontend localhost:3000, backend localhost:8080 running.

**Signup.tsx**
`

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { Link, redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Flex,Heading,Input,Button,InputGroup,Stack,InputLeftElement,chakra,Box,Avatar,FormControl,FormHelperText,InputRightElement, InputElementProps} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { FaUserAlt, FaLock } from "react-icons/fa";
import axios from 'axios';
import { BASE_URL } from './helper/BASE_URL';

const CFaUserAlt = chakra(FaUserAlt);
const CFaLock = chakra(FaLock);

const Signup = () => {
    const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
    const [inputEmail, setInputEmail] = useState("")
    const [inputPassword, setInputPassword] = useState("");
    const handleShowClick = () => setShowPassword(!showPassword);

    const handleInputEmailChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setInputEmail(event.target.value);
    const handleInputPasswordChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setInputPassword(event.target.value);
    const isError = inputEmail === ""

    const onClickSignup = (event: any) => {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        axios.post(BASE_URL + "/signup", {
            email: inputEmail,
            password: inputPassword
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        })
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <Flex
            flexDirection="column"
            width="100wh"
            height="100vh"
            backgroundColor="blue.500"
            justifyContent="center"
            alignItems="center"
            >
            <Stack
            flexDir="column"
            mb="2"
            justifyContent="center"
            alignItems="center"
            >
            <Avatar bg="teal.500" />
            <Heading color="white">新規登録</Heading>
            <Box minW={{ base: "90%", md: "468px" }}>
                <form onSubmit={onClickSignup}>
                    <Stack
                    spacing={4}
                    p="1rem"
                    backgroundColor="whiteAlpha.900"
                    boxShadow="md"
                >
                    <FormControl isInvalid={isError}>
                        <InputGroup>
                            <InputLeftElement
                            pointerEvents="none"
                            children={<CFaUserAlt color="gray.300" />}
                            />
                                <Input type="email" id="email" name='email' value={inputEmail} onChange={handleInputEmailChange} placeholder="メールアドレス" />
                        </InputGroup>
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormControl isInvalid={isError}>
                        <InputGroup>
                            <InputLeftElement
                            pointerEvents="none"
                            color="gray.300"
                            children={<CFaLock color="gray.300" />}
                            />
                            <Input
                            type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
                            id="password"
                            name="password"
                            placeholder="パスワードは6文字以上の英数字で入力"
                            value={inputPassword} onChange={handleInputPasswordChange}
                            />
                                <InputRightElement width="4.5rem">
                                    <Button h="1.75rem" size="sm" onClick={handleShowClick}>
                                    {showPassword ? "Hide" : "Show"}
                                    </Button>
                                </InputRightElement>
                        </InputGroup>
                    </FormControl>
                    <Button
                    borderRadius={0}
                    type="submit"
                    variant="solid"
                    colorScheme="blue"
                    width="full"
                    >
                        登録
                    </Button>
                    </Stack>
                </form>
            </Box>
        </Stack>
        <Box pt="3">
            <Link style={{color: "white"}} to={'/'}>ホームへ</Link>
        </Box>
    </Flex>
            <Link to="/">Homeへ</Link>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Signup
```

`

**UserDetailsServiceImpl.java**
`

```
package com.portfolio.todoapp.asoviewtodo.Service;

import com.portfolio.todoapp.asoviewtodo.Repositopry.UserRepository;
import com.portfolio.todoapp.asoviewtodo.UserDetailsImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.*;

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM asoviewtodo.users WHERE email = ?;";
`your text`            Map<String, Object> map = jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(sql, email);
            String password = (String)map.get("password");
            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority((String)map.get("authority")));
            return new UserDetailsImpl(email, password, authorities);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user not found", e);
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void register(String email, String password, String authority) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO asoviewtodo.users (email, password, authority) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, email, passwordEncoder.encode(password), authority);
    }

}
```

`

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

`

```
package com.portfolio.todoapp.asoviewtodo.Config;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/signup").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().
                disable().cors();
        http.formLogin(login -> login.loginPage("http://localhost:3000/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login").
                defaultSuccessUrl("http://localhost:3000/").failureUrl("/login/error").permitAll()).
                logout(logout -> logout.logoutUrl("http://localhost:3000/login"));
         return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "DELETE"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

`

**UserController.java**
`

```
package com.portfolio.todoapp.asoviewtodo.Controller;

import com.portfolio.todoapp.asoviewtodo.SignupForm;
import com.portfolio.todoapp.asoviewtodo.Service.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000")
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/signup")
    public String newSignup(SignupForm signupForm) {
        return "signup";
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public String signup(@Validated SignupForm signupForm, BindingResult result , Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            userDetailsServiceImpl.register(signupForm.getEmail(), signupForm.getPassword(), "ROLE_USER");
        }catch (DataAccessException e) {
            model.addAttribute("signupError", "fail to signup");
        }

        result.hasErrors();
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "signup";
        }

        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();

        if(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken == false) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        }
        try {
            request.login(signupForm.getEmail(), signupForm.getPassword());
        } catch(ServletException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

`

This is error message image when setting breakpoint on
'
userDetailsServiceImpl.register(signupForm.getEmail(), signupForm.getPassword(), "ROLE_USER");
'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr3BW.jpg)

I tried to set PROXY:http://localhost:8080 on package.json but same error occurs, doesn't work.

I confirmed that I could get and keep value of password on Inspect, so I don't know why this is happening.

I would appreciate it if you would answer to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ***signupForm.getPassword()*** has any value. Might signupForm.getPassword() has **null** value or signupForm instance is not created.

If we look the method of ***BCryptPasswordEncoder*** class you may notice if ***rawPassword*** is null then this error message is returned.

```
@Override
public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
    if (rawPassword == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("rawPassword cannot be null");
    }
    String salt = getSalt();
    return BCrypt.hashpw(rawPassword.toString(), salt);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Subarata!
I set breakpoint on here 'userDetailsServiceImpl.register(signupForm.getEmail(), signupForm.getPassword(), "ROLE_USER");' , Error says email and password both are null.
(I added specific error message image!)
This problem is on backend side?

Answer (score 0):

From your response i can see that the request does not have any value for the email and password. My guess is you are not populating the values correctly. I can see that you are not using @RequestBody anotation on your post method.

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
    public String signup(@RequestBody("signupForm") @Validated SignupForm signupForm, BindingResult result , Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        YOUR CUSTOM LOGIC
}
```

Hope this helps.